# Regexp grabs only last digit

Tags: php, regex

I have a regexp like this

```
'#/somestring/[-a-z0-9]+([0-9]+)/#'
```

And string like this

```
http://www.localhost.dev/somestring/test-2014-test-153/
```

I need to grab "153" part of url, it's a post id, but now i grab only "3", last digit of id part.
I've tried to modify expression with "*", ".", "{1,}", but no success.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, forgot to mention, 'somestring' part, must be checked too, it's a controller route.

Comment: is `http://www.localhost.dev/somestring/test-2014-test-153/` the exact input link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is this simple regex. It will work with or without trailing slash. 1st group will contain the number.

```
somestring\/.+?(\d+)\/?$
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/rA3sX8/2)

(If the last segment of your test case isn't last, then you can use `somestring\/.+?(\d+)\/` - [**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/rA3sX8/3))

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but i forgot to mention, 'somestring' part, must be checked too, it's a controller route. If you can, please modify your answer.

Comment: This does not check if there is some string ahead.Will fail in case of `http://www.localhost.dev/somestring/test-2014-test-153/dfsdfsdfsd`

Comment: @vks I answer to OP not you. If I'm a bit rude, I can't help it, sorry for that. But as far OP's question is concerned, he never told that there would be additional string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will fit your needs:

```
\-([0-9]+)\/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(\d+)/
```

this will work, and also if you're in confusion try a site like
`http://regexpal.com/`

Answer (score 0):

```
somestring\/.*?(\d+)[^\d]*$
```

try this.This will give the last integer irrespective of what's ahead.Just grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/42

Comment: change  `(\d)` to `(\d+)`